# Cancelling a damaged building in Starcraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

I know that cancelling an unfinished building gives you back 75% of the resources you invested.

However, I have the feeling that if an unfinished building is attacked, the percent of damage received is also substracted when cancelled.

Can anyone confirm that?

Anyway, I think that's only fair. If not, you could constantly build pylons (for example) in your opponent's main, forcing him to stop mining, at only the cost of 25 minerals...

Answer (score 4):

You can just test it out yourself; but anyway I can confirm that damage does not affect the amount of resources funded.

You also can't view it as a simple "25 mineral" cost. The mining time lost performing that is already quite substantial in the early game. Further more, that 100 minerals used to build the pylon is also unusable for that period of time. This is a large investment early game. You have to factor in the opportunity cost of that 100 minerals and your probe not mining.

Comment: since when do probes need to do actual constructing? They just initiate the construction and then go on with their work..

Comment: @Bora: Just because the probe isn't constructing like an SCV doesn't mean it's mining. It's in the opponent's base, warping in pylons every 30 seconds.

Comment: @tenfour Oh that.. Yeah, he's busy harrassing. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: OK, thanks. However, I do find it unfair. You get the same from cancelling an almost completed nexus with 100% hit points, and from an almost dead nexus with 10 hit points.

Comment: While sc2 tries to "make logical sense", Blizzard fortunately favors balance over lore. For example it doesn't really make sense that SCVs can't repair themselves, or that fungal growth only affects opponents' units, or that marines can't heal while *inside* a medivac. But "fixing" these behaviors means altering the balance of the game, and on that subject I have no opinion on how damage-affecting-cancellation-refund would change game play.

Answer (score 2):

Damage does not affect the amount refunded when canceling a building. The idea that you can constantly build pylons in the opponent's base to stop them from mining is only something that could maybe work in bronze - silver level.

Comment: Bronze, silver...just where I am ;-)

Comment: You should try it sometime to see how opponents react. My first thought is that your multitasking needs to be pretty crisp otherwise you'll suffer from 1) accidentally letting a pylon finish or 2) messing up your own build because you're focusing too much on this passive harassment. I tried the multitasking trainer custom map and tried to do a 4gate, and magically I was like a minute behind in my build just because I was microing around a probe at the same time.